# Multiple Select Fabric canvas objects by Ctrl Key and set it to Active

Tags: typescript, vue.js, fabricjs

Context:
I'm using `fabricjs` canvas to draw all my `icons/texts` on it. For each `icon/text`, I've set the listener for moved, scaled and rotated:

[image]

Currently it allows only select one object to move, scale and rotate. I'm implementing the feature for multiple select there.

Problem:
I'm trying to find the solution to setting active object for the new selection objects.

I've grouped these selected objects and set it to active by `setActiveObject(newGroup)` on the `selection:updated` event.
But, when I set active objects the `selection:updated` fired again so its in the endless loop until this error occurred:

[image]

Any solution?

There is an issue for the same problem but it's fixed directly on the library function but I'm using yarn/npm. `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62872779/fabricjs-selection-handling-multiple-objects`